# Can't convert double array to String using Apache Commons Lang

Tags: java, arrays, string, double, apache-commons-lang

I have been trying to convert a double array to a string where numbers are separated with a space.

```
public class StringTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double[] g =  {1.2,1.4,1.4} ;
        String d = StringUtils.join(g, " ");
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Commons Lang javadoc tells me that it is possible to do this, code runs as well but I get only `[D@54a50a00` printed out. What is missing here?

Comment: Try with `Double[]`.

Comment: It only prints the space then, nothing else.

Comment: Which version of the library are you using?

Comment: My IDE says that it is calling the `join(T...)` method, where the inferred type of `T` is `Serializable`. That is because there is no method for `join(double[], String)`. You could replace `" "` with `' '`, to use the `join(double[], char)` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are currently using [`StringUtils#join(T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28T...%29). You seem to want to use [`StringUtils#join(double[], char)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#join%28double[],%20char%29). Simply change your `" "` to a `' '`.

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you so much!

Comment: @zamk Note, if you don't know this already, that primitives don't work with generics. But `double[]` is not a primitive, it is a reference type.